# JQuery and Sliders Trouble

Tags: jquery, carousel

Through this link, http://www.basic-slider.com/ , how do you properly do the activation portion to get the slider to work.  It's not working for me.

I tried to add the activation at the end of the HTML.  Is there anything else I'm supposed to do?  There is also a CSS that i linked this all to.

It doesn't appear as a slider.  It appears as all the images are stacked in a row.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Untitled Document</title>
<!-- Include the jQuery library (local or CDN) -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include the plugin *after* the jQuery library -->
<script src="bjqs.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include the basic styles -->
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="bjqs.css"/>

</head>

<body>
<div id="my-slideshow">
    <ul class="bjqs">
  <li><img src="Images/10348456_10152777234672079_8895502383205190278_n.jpg" width="960" height="643" alt=""/></li>
  <li><img src="Images/10357242_10152854252912079_6697226139684450554_n.jpg" width="960" height="643" alt=""/></li>
  <li><img src="Images/10373798_10152777231167079_6764153200051084338_n.jpg" width="960" height="643" alt=""/></li>
  <li><img src="Images/10675514_10152777235022079_7077159589057168251_n.jpg" width="960" height="643" alt=""/></li>
  <li><img src="Images/10382982_10152889566692079_7286817993901058386_n.jpg" width="960" height="643" alt=""/></li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#banner-fade').bjqs({
        'height' : 320,
        'width' : 620,
        'responsive' : true
    });
</script>
```

CSS:

/* Basic jQuery Slider essential styles */

```
ul.bjqs{position:relative; list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;overflow:hidden; display:none;}
li.bjqs-slide{position:absolute; display:none;}
ul.bjqs-controls{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;z-index:9999;}
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li a{position:absolute;}
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li.bjqs-next a{right:0;}
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li.bjqs-prev a{left:0;}
ol.bjqs-markers{list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; width:100%;}
ol.bjqs-markers.h-centered{text-align: center;}
ol.bjqs-markers li{display:inline;}
ol.bjqs-markers li a{display:inline-block;}
p.bjqs-caption{display:block;width:96%;margin:0;padding:2%;position:absolute;bottom:0;}



    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you post more details, like your code, what you have tried, etc.? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you clarify your question so it can be answered better and faster.

Comment: yes, kittycat3141, I will!!

Comment: You forgot the `}` at the end of your function. (To find this, I opened the debug window (usually f12), and it said 'unexpected end of script'. This means you ended the script while you were in the middle of some code.)

Comment: just fixed that! but it still is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the id in your html

so

```
$('#banner-fade').bjqs({
```

should be

```
$('#my-slideshow').bjqs({
```

Comment: is there anything else im missing?  I tried putting changing it to my-slideshow in the body.  Do I need to take off the script tags?  Do I need to put it in the head?  Should there be anything with my-slideshow in the CSS?

Comment: @amv have you downloaded the plugin file and is it in the same directory as the html ? (*as the `<script src="bjqs.min.js"></script>` line implies*).